# Convergence - underdetermined differential systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

I have came to certain problem in a differential question, but I fail to solve it. It is not a homework and is a duplicate question from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3347384/edit).  It is an investigation, than I don't know certainly what must converge, the whole state or it partially.

\begin{equation}
\dot{q}_a + \lambda_a q_a + \alpha_u \dot{q}_u +  \lambda_u q_u = 0
\end{equation}

Please, understimate the problem only if you know the answer.

Best regards,
Bruno

Comment: A typo. And the first question was messy, than I reformulated it.

Comment: So essentially $\dot y+λ_ay+(λ_u-λ_aα_u)q_u=0$ with $y=q_a+α_uq_u$. Given $q_u$, you can solve for $y$ and thus for $q_a$, and $q_u$ is completely free, so everything might happen.

Comment: Than, for $q_u$ and $eig(\lambda_a) \in \mathbb{C}^-$, than the system y is stable, right?

Comment: My intuition wish to converge a submanifold $q_m \in \mathbb{R}^m$ to 0 and not the sum $q_a + \alpha_u q_u$.